# How to insert multiple rows with PDO prepared statmenets based off of a SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've found all of my employee ids (empid) who are in a specified group:

```
$groupid = $_GET['groupid'];
$myquery=$con->prepare("SELECT e.id AS empid FROM employees e WHERE e.groupid=?");
$myquery->execute([$groupid]);
```

I would now like to insert a new row into a different table for EACH employee ID (empid) i found above.

Would anyone be able to explain this to me?

Comment: You loop through the return of your SELECT statement and perform an INSERT with the employee ID.

Comment: How is your question different from running any insert query in a loop?

Comment: Depending on the exact circumstances, you should consider using bulk insert statement or even an insert ... select ... instead simple inserts in a loop.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: The INSERT query I'm used to is: (INSERT INTO mytable (empid) VALUES (?) -- execute([$empid]) -- Would this work?  I know how to loop it to display all the empids in the body of my page, but am not sure how to loop it for the insert statement.  For the body of my page i would use the following...   while ($row = $myquery->fetch()){

Comment: Am I right in thinking you'd like to select all rows from one table (given certain where clauses) into another table (or just parts of the original)?

Comment: In this case use an insert ... select ... No point in retrieving the employee id values in your php application just to insert them again into a different table.

Comment: I just need the empid from the original select query

Comment: I've never heard of insert select, going to research that now.  Thank you. @Shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're trying to select all rows from one table, and insert into another, there are actually various ways of doing this.

Using the code you've started above, you could use a prepared query:

```
$groupid = $_GET['groupid'];
$myquery = $con->prepare("SELECT e.id AS empid FROM employees e WHERE e.groupid = :groupid");
$myquery->execute([':groupid' => $groupid]);

$insert_query = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO new_table (empid) VALUE (:empid)");
$insert_query->bindParam(':empid', $empid);

while ($result = $myquery->fetch()) {
    if ($empid = $result['empid']) {
        $insert_query->execute();
    }
}
```

However, this is rather slow, and instead, I'd recommend a single query:

```
$groupid = $_GET['groupid'];
$con->prepare("INSERT INTO new_table (empid) SELECT e.id FROM employees WHERE groupid = :group_id");
$con->execute(['group_id' => $group_id]);
```

This has the advantage of passing off all the logic to the SQL server, so you're not passing data back to the PHP only for it to be passed back to the SQL server. Obviously, if you need to do any PHP processing, then you'll need the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new prepared with your query, such as:

```
$insert = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO new_table SET empid = :empid");
foreach ($retrieved_ids as $id) {
    $insert->execute([':empid' => $id]);
}
```

You can look into bindValue and bindParam to make use of here as well.